# How to use nextPageToken in Google Analytics API using PHP

Tags: php, google-analytics-api

Good day,

I really want to get the next set of data after getting the first 10,000 data from Google Analytics. After further research there is a thing called nextpagetoken, which is I am trouble getting the next set of data. I have tried it but kept on getting the error an error or there were no data taken. Does someone has the same issue before? Please assist me on this (Sample Code much appreciated). Thank you so much.

Here is my code:

```
 <?php
     $analytics = initializeAnalytics();     
     $response = getReport($analytics);  
     printResults($response);

    function initializeAnalytics()
    {
        $KEY_FILE_LOCATION = __DIR__ . 'MyFileDirectory';
        // Create and configure a new client object.
        $client = new Google_Client();
        $client->setApplicationName("Hello Analytics Reporting");
        $client->setAuthConfig($KEY_FILE_LOCATION);
        $client->setScopes(['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly']);
        $analytics = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting($client);
        return $analytics;
     }

    function getReport($analytics) {
        // Replace with your view ID, for example XXXX.
        $VIEW_ID = "MyViewId";

        // Create the DateRange object.
        $dateRange = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_DateRange();
        $dateRange->setStartDate("2017-04-01");
        $dateRange->setEndDate("2017-06-19");

        // Create the Metrics object.
        $totalEvents = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_Metric();
        $totalEvents->setExpression("ga:totalEvents");
        $totalEvents->setAlias("totalEvents");

        //Create the Dimensions object.
        $clientId = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_Dimension();
        $clientId->setName("ga:dimension4");
        $sessionId = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_Dimension();
        $sessionId->setName("ga:dimension5");
        $eventLabel = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_Dimension();
        $eventLabel->setName("ga:eventLabel");
        $timestamp = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_Dimension();
        $timestamp->setName("ga:dimension3");

        // Create the ReportRequest object.
        $request = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_ReportRequest();
        $request->setViewId($VIEW_ID);
        //set number of rows
        $request->setPageSize(10000);
        $request->setDateRanges($dateRange);
        $request->setMetrics(array($totalEvents));
        $request->setDimensions(array($clientId,$sessionId,$eventLabel, 
        $timestamp));   
        $body = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_GetReportsRequest();
        $body->setReportRequests( array( $request) );
        return $analytics->reports->batchGet( $body );
    }

    function printResults($reports) {
        for ( $reportIndex = 0; $reportIndex < count( $reports ); $reportIndex++ ) 
        {
            $report = $reports[ $reportIndex ];
            $header = $report->getColumnHeader();
            $dimensionHeaders = $header->getDimensions();
            $metricHeaders = $header->getMetricHeader()->getMetricHeaderEntries();
            $rows = $report->getData()->getRows();  
            echo '<table border="1">';

            for ( $rowIndex = 0; $rowIndex < count($rows); $rowIndex++) {
                $row = $rows[ $rowIndex ];
                $dimensions = $row->getDimensions();
                $metrics = $row->getMetrics();
                echo '<tr>';     

                for ($i = 0; $i < count($dimensionHeaders) && $i < count($dimensions); $i++) 
                {
                    echo '<td>' . ": " . $dimensions[$i] . "\n" .'</td>';
                }
                for ($j = 0; $j < count($metrics); $j++) {
                    $values = $metrics[$j]->getValues();
                    for ($k = 0; $k < count($values); $k++) {
                        $entry = $metricHeaders[$k];
                        echo '<td>'  . ": " . $values[$k] . "\n" .'</td>' ;
                    }
                    echo '</tr>';
                }
            }
            echo '</table>';
      }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to get `nextPageToken` value from each response and set to every next request:

```
$client = new \Google_Client();
/* ... */
$analytics = new \Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting($client);
$request = new \Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_ReportRequest();
$request->setViewId($view);
$request->setMetrics($metrics);
$request->setDateRanges($dateRange);
$request->setPageSize(10000);
/* ... */
$body = new \Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_GetReportsRequest();
$body->setReportRequests(array($request));
do {
    $response = $analytics->reports->batchGet($body, $params);
    /* ...
    Processing $response
    ... */
    $request->setPageToken($response[0]->getNextPageToken());
} while ($response[0]->getNextPageToken() != '');
```

Comment: I tried the code provided above but i got empty screen. May I clarify in what particular line should I insert the code you have provided? Apologies, newbie here.

Comment: who is $params?